# Vaadin - ListSelect - set focus on selected item?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm currently using the ListSelect component of Vaadin (version 7.x) and would like to highlight the option I've set as the default selection using the setValue() method - similar to what happens for the onClick() event when the background colour changes to blue and the text colour to white.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
ListSelect itemList = new ListSelect("Please select an item:");

itemList.add(initialItem)

for(Item item: items) {
    if(!item.equals(initialItem.getName())) {
        //add item
    }
itemList.setValue(initialItem.getName());

//set focus on intial item to make it stand out from all other items
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
itemList.select(initialItem)
```